# checking javascript hooks and calls

Tags: javascript, html, firebug, reverse-engineering

Is there a way that you can check the javascript used on an html element ? ie. if my javascript was in an external js script would there be a way to check which part of the js realted to that html object, in the same way you can use firebug to check which css elements are attached to the html ?

Comment: in Chrome: Inspect an element / on the right side / last entry "Event Listeners"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a very cool [plugin](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) that will help you in this case.

Here is the live [DEMO](http://sprymedia.co.uk/VisualEvent/demo/)